# Formulate correlated subqueries (row-wise check of condition) in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables. The first table looks like this:

```
CompanyID  | TIMESTAMP           | NewsitemID 
---------------------------------------------    
ID1        | 2000-01-06 15:00:00 | 1       
ID2        | 2000-01-06 15:32:00 | 2
ID1        | 2000-01-07 14:00:00 | 3
ID3        | 2000-01-07 17:00:00 | 4
```

Now I want to update the timestamp if it falls inbetween two consecutive Closingtimes given in the second table. The new timestamp should be the second of the two consecutive entries as indicated by the corresponding SelectedTimestamp. This is the second table:

```
Closingtime         | SelectedTimestamp 
-----------------------------------------          
2000-01-05 16:00:00 | --
2000-01-06 16:00:00 | 2000-01-06 16:00:00
2000-01-07 16:00:00 | 2000-01-07 16:00:00
2000-01-10 16:00:00 | 2000-01-10 16:00:00
```

So, what I want to achieve is:

```
CompanyID  | TIMESTAMP           | NewsitemID | NewTimestamp
-------------------------------------------------------------------    
ID1        | 2000-01-06 15:00:00 | 1          | 2000-01-06 16:00:00    
ID2        | 2000-01-06 15:32:00 | 2          | 2000-01-06 16:00:00
ID1        | 2000-01-07 14:00:00 | 3          | 2000-01-07 16:00:00
ID3        | 2000-01-07 17:00:00 | 4          | 2000-01-10 16:00:00
```

But I am pretty new to Snowflake SQL and have problems even with starting the query. I have figured that I could probably use something in the direction of

```
SELECT SelectedTimestamp 
WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN lower_bound AND upper_bound
```

but I have no clue how to "loop" through the lower and upper bounds given by the ClosingTime.

Any hint on how I could proceed here would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Your question could use some clarifications, see my comment.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it's clearer now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what is the expected behavior you want, as the second table columns are identical.
Also, you didn't specify what "lower/upper bounds" mean for you, but I'll assume you mean two consecutive rows.

In either case, Snowflake actually has pretty rich support for subqueries. Hopefully this is what you need:

```
select first.*, 
(select min(selectedtimestamp) 
  from second where closingtime > first.timestamp) as newtimestamp 
from first;
-----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
 COMPANYID |      TIMESTAMP      | NEWSITEMID |    NEWTIMESTAMP     |
-----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
 id1       | 2000-01-06 15:00:00 | 1          | 2000-01-06 16:00:00 |
 id2       | 2000-01-06 15:32:00 | 2          | 2000-01-06 16:00:00 |
 id3       | 2000-01-07 14:00:00 | 3          | 2000-01-07 16:00:00 |
 id4       | 2000-01-07 17:00:00 | 4          | 2000-01-10 16:00:00 |
-----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
```